# Where can one find the list of all functions available under firebase-admin? firebase-functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm testing out writing code with Firebase Cloud Functions.

with

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
```

Where can one find the list of all functions available under admin, or functions, or any other popular or recommended firebase or Node.js sets of functions?

btw shouldn't there be a firebase-cloud-functions tag?

Comment: Questions about using Google Cloud Functions with Firebase are tagged as [google-cloud-functions][firebase]. No separate tag is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The `admin` module you import is the Firebase Admin SDK for node. It is documented in [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) and [this API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/).

The `functions` module you import is the Cloud Functions library for Firebase. It is documented in [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) and in [this API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/).